# Детский вопрос о выражении «ещё не вечер»

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология, смысл

Сегодня (в передаче "60 минут"; ~19.40):
*— Я считаю, что Килинкаров был бы прекрасным премьер-министром Украины.

— Ещё не вечер!*

Девочка (9 лет) удивилась, и далее состоялся приблизительно такой диалог:
— Как же не вечер? Уже темно. Вечер.
— Ну... Вообще-то ночь, потому что солнце уже село.
— Так почему же сказали "еще не вечер"?

Вы знаете, я запуталась в собственных рассуждениях. Помогите, пожалуйста, доходчиво объяснить ребенку, что это такое и когда — "еще не вечер"?

Comment: И. Резник. «Еще не вечер, еще не вечер,
Еще в запасе время есть у нас с тобой.»

Comment: Да, конечно, это я помню. И Высоцкого — тоже (https://www.culture.ru/poems/19375/eshyo-ne-vecher).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это фразеологизм.
Значение: *ещё не всё упущено, ещё есть возможности*.
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/ещё_не_вечер](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80)

Не стоит вдаваться в упрощение для детей, можно объяснить как есть, главное — самому чётко понимать, сложность лишь в этом.

Можно добавить следующее: вечером уже поздно куда-то идти, заниматься чем-то серьёзным, ну и хочется спать, поэтому так говорят.

Что интересно, так это то, что данное выражение не только означает "*ещё не поздно*", но и намекает на то, что **ещё всё может быть**. И думаю, что это в данном случае важнее. Скорее всего, этот смысл и закладывался. Раз говорят, что "был бы" (стилистически корректнее: *мог бы быть*), то и так понятно, что ещё не поздно, если не имеется в виду какой-то период в прошлом (а тогда: был бы в то время, но и сейчас не поздно).

Значение "*ещё не всё упущено*" хорошо объясняет суть выражения, но здесь не совсем подходит, потому что предложение позитивное, не сказано о проблемах и упущениях.

---

Примечание: чаще всего выражение от первого лица и означает "*ещё посмотрим*" — с намёком, что будут предприняты действия, а здесь говорится про третье лицо.

Примечание 2: там может иметься в виду то, что мнение может поменяться, с намёком на то, что он не был бы прекрасным, — то есть значение "*ещё всё может поменяться*", и с оттенком "*ещё есть возможности для этого*" (как по словарю), но это маловероятно. Контекста маловато для стопроцентного понимания. Там важную роль играет интонация. Лучше бы привести ссылку на видео с таймингом (и чтобы никто не искал).

Comment: Интересно, что как фразеологизм выражение имеется только в Викисловаре. И еще интересно, что появилось оно сравнительно недавно. Самый ранний пример из Нацкорпуса:  ― Еще не вечер, ― говорит Коростелев, ― мы не знаем, где Стрелкин предел. [В. Ф. Панова. Ясный берег (1949)] (https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?dpp=10&format=html&g=i_doc&kwsz=5&lang=ru&mode=main&nodia=1&out=normal&p=7&req=%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80&sampling=1&sort=i_grtagging&spd=10&spp=50&sr=1&text=lexform)

Comment: Девочка, судя по вопросу, не осознаёт даже того, что эфир может передаваться как запись в любое время дня , и две точки зрения на фразу — "уже поздно куда-то идти" и "ещё всё будет"— её надолго отправят в аут.

Comment: @shampar А может, это онлайн-трансляция.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Это точно фразеологизм, потому что о непосредственно вечере речи нет. Наверно, объяснение стоит начать с того, что такое фразеологизм (когда под несколькими словами понимается что-то другое, не дословно). Можно и без правила — привести самые простые примеры, сравнить дословное значение и фразеологическое. Ещё важно сказать, что иногда о значении фразеологизма можно догадаться, а в остальных случаях нужно посмотреть в словаре.

Comment: В ответ добавлены примечания.

Comment: Вчера не было возможности воспользоваться компьютером. Сегодня же нашлась любопытная информация (http://endic.ru/winged/Esche-ne-vecher-3379.html). Спасибо за Ваши подсказки и примечания. Мы почти разобрались.

Comment: Там хорошее значение: *ничего, несмотря на неудачи, мы еще себя покажем*. Но в данном случае применяется и без неудач, что скорее исключение. И "*ещё не всё потеряно*" хорошее. Ключевое — неудачи либо проблемы, стремление к тому, чтобы исправить ситуацию.

Comment: Примечание 3: передать суть выражения (что делают словари) — это хорошо, но самое точное значение то, которое можно подставить в пример. Пока мне самой близкой заменой (в общем) кажется "*ещё посмотрим*".

Comment: Ответ подправлен много где. Кое-что добавлено. Можно перечитать.

Comment: Чувствую, Вы потратили много времени на ответ. Еще раз спасибо за Ваше мнение. Ссылку на видео предоставить нет возможности: СМОТРИМ не пускает, а Yoytube почему-то отсылает на другую платформу. (Жаль, что сам вопрос Вам не понравился.) Ребенок, правда, после всех рассуждений-объяснений решил, что лучше было бы сказать "Еще не ночь".

Comment: Кучу времени иногда занимает грам. выражение своих мыслей, постоянно какие-то логические ошибки — обычно их мало, а в этот раз очень много, — а иначе порой и не формулируется (это очень демотивирует). А также привык читать поверхностно, и чего-то не замечаю, а расплата за это высокая: потом приходится переделывать, дабы всё было правильно. Часа 2 заняло вместе с комментариями, сам в шоке. Раз ребёнок мало что понял, можно не париться и сказать, что здесь оно значит "ещё всё может быть". Просто ставлю лайк, когда узнаю что-то новое, это не тот случай, но мне не жалко. Вопрос оказался непростым.

Answer (score 2):

Такие вещи вообще не обязательно кому-либо объяснять: это естественный процесс усвоения языка — когда человек снова и снова слышит слово или сочетание и понимает особенности употребления этого слова или сочетания. Вам же никто не объяснял значение этого сочетания, но вы понимаете его фигуральный характер. К тому же в данной ситуации девочка, скорее всего, вообще не слушала ‟политический дискурс”, а просто услышала это сочетание в отрыве от всего остального. Скорее всего, если бы данное сочетание было в рамках простой сказки и отчетливо понятного для ребенка диалога, то фигуральный характер сочетания даже не пришлось бы пояснять. (Можете найти рассказ с таким сочетанием и проверить.)
Если все же объяснять такое сочетание, то это то же самое, что и ‟еще не поздно”. Для выполнения различных условий в реальном мире есть сроки, после который условие становится невыполнимым, и вот отсутствие истечения такого срока и называют ‟еще не вечер”. ‟Еще не вечер” = еще есть время для выполнения определенного условия. Истечение сроков метафорически обозначают словом ‟вечер”, поскольку у вечера есть эта характеристика, что в данное время нельзя разрешить хоть сколько-нибудь серьезную проблему, выполнить какую-то объемную работу, почти все службы уже не работают, вообще нельзя выполнить какую-либо физическую работу (вроде рытья канав) и т.д.